# Move to next UIViewcontroller, while data to be displayed there, is still loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am writing an ios app, that has multiple UIViewcontrollers. They all have UITableViews that are filled with data, that is acquired from different API's. But the problem that I am facing is that, when I tap on a cell, the the app won't navigate to the next page, until the data for that page is acquired. This make the app look, mighty slow. I need some way to navigate to next page, where I can put some spinner animation to let the user know that it is acquiring data(atleast). I don't want the user to think that the app has crashed, or something(it stays in the same page for solid 7-10 seconds)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should call all the api in the background so it wont effect the main thread, use the queue for call api in background queue like below.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
//call apis here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is,You can call the API using dispatch queue,So that it will not affect other functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these simple steps

ViewController1 = VC1

ViewController1 = VC2

in VC1

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC2 animated:YES];
```

in VC2

```
@implementation {
    BOOL hasData;
}
-(void)viewDidLoad { 
    hasData = NO;
    [self getAndShowData];
}
-(void)getAndShowData {
    // Start Showing Spinner
    // load your data from server and 
    // on success 
    1.) hasData = YES;
    2.) Call reload tableview
    // Remove spinner

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     if(hasData == NO) return 0;
     return actual number of rows.
}
```

}